# small conformation on activity life cycle

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

As i am new to Android i need clarify some doubts in **Activity** Life cycle.
I have two activities A and B.
I launched first Activity **A** and i called Activity **B** from Activity **A**.
So, Activity **A** went into **onPause()** state and **onStart()** state will start for Activity **B**.
Now i pressed **BACK** key in Acitivity **B**.So, automatically **onResume()** method of Activity **A** will start.

> Then what is state of Activity **B**?? **onPause()** or **onStop()**?
>   Again if we press **BACK** key in Activity **A** what will happen? It goes to Activity **B** or close the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then what is state of Activity B?

If you hit the back key then, unless you overrode `onBackPressed()`, the Activity will be finished (`finish()`). -> The Activity state will be destroyed (`onDestroy()`).

> Again if we press BACK key in Activity A what will happen?

Activity A will also be finished and the app will close itself (since there is no other Activity in the backstack).

Comment: what about my First Q? Means State of B?

Answer (score 1):

AS we pressing back button Activity B should be destroyed 
After that we are again going back from Activity A hence application should close